# Style identification

Tags: images, illustration, stock-images

I'm looking for the exact name to write to find this type/style of illustration.
I need this same type of illustration but with animals. Any ideas how to look for this and / or where to find this?

Thanks!

[image: source: https://sagacify.com/]

Comment: Related on Arts & Crafts: https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/whats-the-name-of-this-cartoon-style. Similar in style, but with more gradients.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything has a name.

This *may be* vector artwork, but not necessarily..

... other than that your guess is as good as anyone else's guess.

Comment: But 'vector artwork' is not a style, but a name based on technique, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Agreed.. but there's no particular name for this style. It's *not* "flat design" as suggested at arts and crafts... there's transparency effects in the sample which are not part of flat design. Seams many use "flat design" as a catch-all for *anything* which may be vector-based.

Answer (score 0):

Stock image websites are loaded with identical style illustration work.

While they may not be filed under a specific name, you could get some indication by looking at the description and tags of such stock photos.

The people posting these are most likely the best people to describe these.